# distance measure used to calculate k nearest neighbour

Tags: machine-learning, vector, distance, knn, euclidean-distance

I am reading about k nearest neighbour, and the distance measure given in the example is as below.

It says Ri is the range of the i-th component. I am confused about which distance measure is used here? I understand Euclidean Distance but this doesn't seem to be it. Could you help to explain what "range of the i-th component" is and which distance measure is this? Many thanks. Please let me know if more information is needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range is difference between max and min of that feature (column) in the training dataset.

You can think about this as `L1` norm since we are taking just the absolute distance between the max and min. This is commonly done to normalize the distance calculation across features so that some feature should not dominate the distance calculation.

Comment: Thanks. But could you explain a bit more? it's only talking about two vectors right? For example given two vectors [a1, a2, a3, labelA] and [b1,b2,b3, labelB], what is the range say at i=1, or i=2 ?

Comment: My understanding is that it calculates range from the training dataset and not from the given two points. Meaning Range comes from whole training dataset

Comment: But if that's the case what does i-th component refer to?

Comment: let us say, your training dataset has 15 records and each has 10 features/ dimensions. Then i th component means the one of out of those 10 featuers. Simply the components are the columns in the training dataset. Hope it helps

Comment: So you mean say my training dataset has 3 records [a1, a2, a3, labelA],  [b1,b2,b3, labelB] and [c1, c2, c3, labelA]. They each has 3 features. For i=1, the range R is the difference between the max (lets say it's c1), and the min (say it's a1), R1= c1-a1 ?

Comment: ya, exactly. In each column max-min

Answer (score 1):

The formula given is just for the Euclidean Distance, except that the normalization of data is done in place when calculating the distance.

Normalization of data is necessary for KNN because if not done then the features with higher values will be dominant in deciding the output.
The above formula for KNN omits the explicit step of normalization and does it in place while calculating the distance.

NOTE:- Here, `i` denotes the i<sup>th</sup> column and not row.

Here, is the actual explanation of the formula,

R<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub><sup>max</sup> - x<sub>i</sub><sup>min</sup>

While normalization we transform each row using the following transformation,

x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> / (x<sub>i</sub><sup>max</sup> - x<sub>i</sub><sup>min</sup>)

So, when computing for the distance the formula is effective,

d<sup>2</sup> = ((a<sub>1</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>)-(b<sub>1</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>))<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + ((a<sub>2</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>)-(b<sub>2</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>))<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + ((a<sub>n</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>)-(b<sub>n</sub> - x<sup>min</sup>))<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>

which is effectively,

d<sup>2</sup> = (a<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + (a<sub>2</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + (a<sub>n</sub>- b<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup> / R<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>

, which is shown in the above image.